# Why is drop-shadow changing the way text appears

Tags: css, box-shadow

Why is the drop-shadow on the black bar changing the way the text is displayed? I spent all day yesterday trying to figure out what css was changing my text. I finally narrowed it down to the drop-shadow.

I have tried changing the x,y offsets of the shadow, adding a background color to the text area, adding no drop-shadow css to the text area, stuff with z-index but cant get the text to display as it does without the shadow.

[Sample of how text changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXQqv.png)

```
<style>
body{ font-family: "Arial","Helvetica",
sans- serif;margin:0;left:0;top:0;font:24px Arial;
min-width:900px;display: block; margin: 0 0 1em;}

#blackbar {height:30px;padding:4px 10px 2px;background:#000000;
box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);position:fixed;
left:0;top:0;width:100%;z-index:150;}

.date-area {float:left; color: white; padding-top: 5px 30px
;position: relative;}
</style>


<style>
body {background:#fff;}
</style>

<style>
    body {}  
</style>

<div>
<div id="blackbar">                  
<div class="date-area" id="datetxt" >Some text goes here 123456789</div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Cannot replicate - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/XZeQzG

Comment: Using Fire Fox 50